# highcharts click on data point throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working with highcharts at the moment, and I wanting to trigger a function when a user clicks on a data point.

My highcarts config looks like this,

```
this.chartOptions = {
            chart : {
                //height: (5 * self.categories.length) + 100,
                width : self.$('.graph-holder').width()
            },
            title: {
                useHTML: true,
                text: '<span class="divided"><a href="#" class="js-graph-number js-change-graph" data-dataset="total">Number of projects [' + title.totalNumber + ']</a></span>' +
                      '<span class=""><a href="#" class="js-graph-value js-change-graph" data-dataset="value">Value of projects [' + title.totalVal + '(' + self.model.get('currency') + ')]</a></span>'
            },
            legend : {
                enabled : false
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: yAxisLabels
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled : false,
                crosshairs: {
                    color: '#636363',
                    dashStyle: 'solid',
                    width: '1px'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function (event) {
                                console.log(this);
                                self.showClientProjects(this.category, this.series.options.status, this.clientX, this.plotY);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: data
        };

        this.chart = $('.graph-holder').highcharts(this.chartOptions);
```

Whenever I click on data point it get the following error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of null

What could be causing this? My graph is a line graph that can output multiple series. Sorry I cannot get this on jsfiddle at the moment. So I found a fiddle example of what I want to happen,

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-click/

If I put this example into my code, I still get the error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of null

which is this line in particular in the hightcharts source,

```
if (fn.call(el, eventArguments) === false) {
    eventArguments.preventDefault();
}
```

Only differences are that I am running jquery 2 and the graph is in a bootstrap tab.

Comment: add a breakpoint and see what's the problem

Comment: Something in `self.showClientProjects`?

Comment: @giannisf added a break further information error in question.

Comment: @HalvorStrand added more information certainly no the self.showClientProjects call